# Custom Module: Blocks and Templates not display

Tags: magento-1.9

I have custom module and created controller. It works perfect. But I can not get block. My files are as below:

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sevenbits_Demo>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Sevenbits_Demo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <demo>
            <class>Sevenbits_Demo_Model</class>
            </demo>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <demo>
            <class>Sevenbits_Demo_Helper</class>
            </demo>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <demo>
            <class>Sevenbits_Demo_Block</class>
            </demo>
        </blocks>
    </global>
 <!-- Frontend Controller started here -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <demo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                        <frontName>Demo</frontName>
                       <module>Sevenbits_Demo</module>
                </args>
            </demo>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <demo>
                    <file>demo.xml</file>
                </demo>

            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <!-- Frontend Controller end here -->
</config>
```

**demo.xml** (layout/demo.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
       <demo_index_index>

            <referance name="content">
             <block type="core/template" template="demo/welcome.phtml"></block>

            </referance>
        </demo_index_index>
</layout>
```

**welcome.phtml**

```
<h1>welcome to world of heaven.</h1>
```

**IndexController.php** (controllers/IndexController.php)

```
<?php

class Sevenbits_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
       // print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        return $this->renderLayout();

    }
}
```

**Welcome.php** (Block/Welcome.php)

```
<?php
class  Sevenbits_Demo_Block_Welcome extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public  function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        $this->setTemplate("demo/welcome.phtml");
    }
}
```

Debug through this one:

```
 print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => default [1] => STORE_default [2] => THEME_frontend_rwd_default [3] => demo_index_index [4] => customer_logged_out )
```

Output is this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PWEkckbXCURG9Qdk14YzdEZW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this code does not have permission on google drive

Comment: Please try this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PWEkckbXCURG9Qdk14YzdEZW8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <layout version="0.1.0">
       <demo_index_index>    
            <referance name="content">
               <block type="core/template" template="demo/welcome.phtml"></block>    
            </referance>
        </demo_index_index>
     </layout>
```

You have typo mistake in layout file demo.xml shoud be **reference** instead of **referance**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <layout version="0.1.0">
       <demo_index_index>    
            <reference name="content">
               <block type="core/template" template="demo/welcome.phtml"></block>    
            </reference>
        </demo_index_index>
     </layout>
```

Comment: this is not issue

Comment: What do you get when you run demo/index/index in url

Comment: @Mohit Kumar Arora : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42424/what-is-the-suggested-value-of-max-execution-time-and-memory-limit-for-20-000-pro

Comment: @VasimVanzara updated answer check it

Answer (score 1):

in `demo.xml`, change `block type` to `demo/welcome` instead `core/template`, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <demo_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="demo/welcome" template="demo/welcome.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
     </demo_index_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: still having an issue

Comment: in controller, change `return $this->renderLayout();` TO `$this->renderLayout();`

Comment: Nothing happen.

Comment: It seems no error then, try to flush cache. Also check paths of all folders and files

Comment: I have already disable cache as well as flush manually from var